# Convert A Multidimensional Array To A Simple Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert a multidimensional array to a simple array. Some parts of my code is working, but I am lost when I have to preserve a child array. Here is the main array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattr
            [value] => 250
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrtel
            [value] => 9830293789
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrcolor
            [value] => #2764C6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrta
            [value] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrcb
            [value] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrmcb[1]
            [value] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrmcb[4]
            [value] => 40
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrmrdo
            [value] => 20
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => scattrselect
            [value] => 30
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => pwpus-shortcode-nonce
            [value] => 028c9426c5
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => _wp_http_referer
            [value] => /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
        )

)
```

And, my PHP to convert it in simple array:

```
$new = array();

foreach ( $datas as $data ) { // $datas as being the multidimensional array.
    $new[$data['name']] = $data['value'];
}
```

Now, a `print_r` of `$new` gives me:

```
Array
(
    [scattr] => 250
    [scattrtel] => 9830293789
    [scattrcolor] => #2764C6
    [scattrta] => gdkwsdghwkdhgk
    [scattrcb] =>
    [scattrmcb[1]] => 10
    [scattrmcb[4]] => 40
    [scattrmrdo] => 20
    [scattrselect] => 30
    [pwpus-shortcode-nonce] => 028c9426c5
    [_wp_http_referer] => /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
)
```

So, I think my code is somewhat working, but not preserving that `scattrmcb[1]` and `scattrmcb[4]` in an array. Should give something like this:

```
[scattrmcb] => Array
            (
                [1] => 10
                [4] => 40
            )
```

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Misunderstood at first, edited...

Comment: Totally an aside, but `data` is plural, the singular is `datum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `array_column()` will get you most of the way.  I used a regex to get the key and the inner array index and then `eval() != evil`:

```
foreach(array_column($datas, 'value', 'name') as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/(.*)(\[\d+\])$/', $key, $match)) {
        eval("\$new['{$match[1]}']{$match[2]} = $value;");
    } else {
        $new[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Maybe a more or less readable `eval()`:

```
        eval('$new["'.$match[1].'"]'.$match[2].' = $value;');
```

Comment: OP wants to convert string `scattrmcb[4]` to array like `[scattrmcb][4]`. Does your code help with this?

Comment: In a fatter of fact, your first answer served me better. Just omitted the need of the key=>value pair from the child array and I was all good. Thanks mate, that really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need more logic:

```
<?php
$datas = [
    ['name'=>'scattr', 'value'=>250],
    ['name'=>'scattrmcb[1]', 'value'=>10],
    ['name'=>'scattrmcb[4]', 'value'=>40]
];

$new = array();

foreach ( $datas as $data ) { // $datas as being the multidimensional array.
    // 'scattrmcb' is special so handle it here
    if(substr($data['name'], 0, 9) === 'scattrmcb'){
        // Set the 'scattrmcb' index
        if(!isset($new[substr($data['name'], 0, 9)])){
            $new[substr($data['name'], 0, 9)] = [];
        }

        // Use preg_replace to set a sub-array to the value between []
        $new[substr($data['name'], 0, 9)][preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $data['name'])] = $data['value'];
    }
    else{
        $new[$data['name']] = $data['value'];
    }
}

print_r($new);
```